# Create a domain on server to have all users on it + shared SQL Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, domain

I'm new to Active Directory Domain Services and to Windows Servers in general.
I created a domain on Windows Server 2008 R2 using AD DS and I joined all company's PCs to this domain.
Now what I want is to Install SQL Server 2012 on a server to access its instance from these same PCs (and later TFS too). What I currently found is that I can't install it on the same server since SQL Server cannot be installed on a domain controller.
So what should I do here?

1- Is there any way to install SQL Server on the same server?

2- Should I get a new server and use it for SQL and TFS?

3- If I get a new server and install SQL on it, PCs on the specified domain will still be able to access SQL on the server even if it's not in the same domain?

Sorry but I'm so confused, I'm a real beginner with these issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should not install SQL Server on your Domain Controller.
2. Yes
3. Join the new server to the same domain as the clients. Why would you do otherwise?

Comment: Yes you're right, I realized that, I think I was a bit panicked!
Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: I'm new to serverfault, maybe you can help me to know why my question would get -1 to not do the same error in future questions please. Thanks.

Comment: I'd only add that, although not recommended by MS, SQL Server **can** be installed on DC. I have a Windows 2012 DC running MSSQL Standard 2014 without issues (and it used to run 2012 Trial and Professional editions in the past). When you need to have an SQL Server dedicated machine, why not to have one more DC?

Comment: From [Can I install SQL Server on a domain controller?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2011/07/01/can-i-install-sql-server-on-a-domain-controller.aspx): Security issue: You cannot run SQL Server services on a domain controller under a local service account or a network service account. Functional issue: After SQL Server is installed on a computer, you cannot change the computer from a domain controller to a domain member. The reverse applies as well. There are also a whole host of other issues that come up when running the Windows Internal Database on a DC. Also performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using Hyper-V to install these servers as virtual instances on the same hardware.  A second server as a host would easily support all this.  I would also recommend adding a second domain controller as a VM to back up the first.

Comment: So, just to be sure I got it right, you mean I use Hyper-V on my current server to install two virtual servers, one to be my domain controller and one to install SQL Server and TFS?
If so, is it better than having two different physical servers? (security wise)

Comment: Depending on the level of reliability you need to build in, you might want two physical servers. The added benefit is two domain controllers. But only you can decide the best way.